# Is a type of a object primary expression in c++?

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer

I know a `primary expression` is only literal, this, ( expression ), id-expression. And according to [C++ primary expressions - Is it primary expression or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17259531/c-primary-expressions-is-it-primary-expression-or-not), a primary expression could be defined as

> units that are atomic in the sense that they cannot be decomposed further

So could be a generic Type decomposed to any other expressions? (Thus would not be a primary expression by itself). Which is what compiler says, *generic* Type is **not** primary expression, which means it *could* be further decomposed:

```
template <class T>
T foo(T param)
{
    return T;
}
```

which gives:

```
error: expected primary-expression before ‘;’ token
     return T;
```

So if type `T` is not primary (according to compiler), what would it decomposed into?

Comment: *"primary expression could be defined as units that are atomic"* The missing part in this definition is that primary expression has to actually *be an expression*.

Comment: You’re focusing on the wrong part of “primary expression“. A type is not a primary expression because it’s not an expression, not because it can be decomposed.

Comment: "units that are atomic in the sense that they cannot be decomposed further" is not a part of the definition of *primary-expression* either. `(x + 10)` is a *primary-expression*. This whole question makes no sense

Comment: I added another answer to the other question

Answer (score 3):

You clearly know that there is a [list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/expressions) of what is considered a primary-expression and type is simply not one of them. Decomposing of type, in an expression sense, does not make sense because type cannot be considered as an expression.